# webViewDidFinishLoad fires before the actual graph load from the URL

Tags: javascript, ios, webview

I am loading a graph which is being plotted by Nitro JS on web view on native IOS. I have the URL that trigger the load of Graph. I am facing problem because webViewDidFinishLoad getting fire before the actual graph loads completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to know when a page has totally loaded is to do it yourself - attach JavaScript event listeners into the page being loaded and get them to call your shouldStartLoadWithRequest: with some proprietary url. You could, for example, create a JS function to listen for a window load or dom ready event etc. depending upon if you need to know when the page has loaded, or if just the dom had loaded etc. Depending upon your needs.

If the web page is not your's then you can put this javascript into a file and inject it into every page you load.

For example here is the JavaScript to detect when the dom has loaded in a form that can be injected into the loading page from within the UIWebView and then result in a call to shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (this would invoke shouldStartLoadWithRequestwhen: the dom has finished loadeding, which is before the full page content has been displayed, to detect this just change the event listener).

Something like this in sketch form:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');  
script.type = 'text/javascript';  
script.text = function DOMReady() {
    document.location.href = "mydomain://DOMIsReady";
}

function addScript()
{        
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', DOMReady, false);
}
addScript();
```

But this isn't still 100% complete because DOMContentLoaded doesn't wait until all resources (e.g., images) are loaded (see here http://ie.microsoft.com/TEStdrive/HTML5/DOMContentLoaded/Default.html) so some tweaking may still be required.
If you write the page being loaded/javascript being executed you'll know when its finished so can tailor the code as appropriate. If you didn't write the page then the js being injected might have to be enhanced beyond the above to take the fact DOMContentLoaded doesn't wait into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite likely that the page loading is actually complete (from a browser perspective) before the JS on the page is done executing. Depending on the structure of the JS on the page this may, in fact, be intended behavior, for example it may be desirable for the page to be viewable while the graph still loads asynchronously. If you have direct control of the JS you may be able to alter this behavior.